# Why was Breaking Bad's (and other shows) "Intro" so short?

Tags: breaking-bad, title-sequence

The intro to Breaking Bad is very short - how was this negotiated?  Usually, and especially for more popular shows (in the later seasons), shows have relatively long intros.

Breaking Bad's is about [18 seconds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1HNuAE9WdU), only credits the Creator, Vince Gilligan.

I was wondering how common such short intros are, or was this just really good negotiation on Vince's part, or ...what?

Is it because the other credits follow (during the show), so FX was willing to give it a shorter "title-card" intro?

Edit: If not Breaking Bad specifically, any comments on shorter intros more broadly are welcome!  And also, it's an answer if I'm incorrect in my assumption and it's no big deal.

Comment: There are plenty of shows with very short title sequences. And if you pay attention, you'll notice even shows with longer sequences often have plenty of credits during the first few minutes after the title sequence.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - Hm, true.  They're (in what I can recall) certainly more rare to have a sub 30-second intro.  I am just wondering why/how that's determined.

Comment: Lost followed a similar style - with a short title sequence, followed by credits appearing over the first few minutes of the show.

Comment: Why did they need to "negotiate" this with the broadcaster?  (honest question) ... why do you think this would be a problem for the broadcaster?

Comment: IIRC How I Met Your Mother and Last Man Standing both have short title sequences: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPLOsabhQSM (couldn't find LMS, I think it's a pair of boots being dropped). Arguably Seinfeld even completely lacked a title sequence. The Life In Pieces title sequence also amounts to little more than the title, IIRC.

Comment: @iandotkelly - ...I don't know! I just figured with how technical Hollywood can be (e.g. [What's the difference between “and” and “&” in movie credits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/77942/29308)), I kind of assumed (wrongly I suppose) that the title/intro credit sequence would also be a negotiation of some kind.

Comment: Frasier's title sequence was the first really short one I remember. It's about 10 seconds long. I was curious why this was. I always assumed it was because broadcasters want to cram more commercials in, so if you still want to write 22 minutes of material, you need to cut something, and titles/credits don't affect the plot.

Comment: There was a phase in the early to mid-2000s when opening title sequences fell out of favour and a fair number of TV shows only had a quick splash screen.  Breaking Bad falls into this category.  It still happens from time to time, although longer sequences are making a comeback lately.  IIRC, there was even an episode of *Stargate SG-1* that parodied this trend, although that show retained a longer sequence for all the other episodes.

Comment: Blindspot's intro is [10 seconds long](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKBps9VNFCY)

Comment: Castle had a short intro..

Comment: Fear The Walking Dead also has a very short intro which only credits the show creators and is also on AMC.

Comment: well, The Blacklist is also just 8 seconds! Then credits during the first scenes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J7fSMS782o

Comment: LOST also has a very short into - I think it's just a stylistic choice that plays to tone. Like obviously True Blood, Game of Thrones, Frontier, Outlander, Boardwalk Empire, Westworld, and The Good Fight have really interesting longer opening themes with unique visuals and score that help get you in the mood/mindset. But that doesn't necessarily suit every show like LOST or Black Mirror whose opening and musical score/sounds are shorter and to the point and sort of feeds into the mystery aspects more.

Comment: Reminds me of one of the parody episodes of Stargate SG1 (may have been "300") where they joke about a sci-fi show and having a short intro, before suddenly having a short intro (the first one in the series I believe).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Shorter sequences save time for audiences, and money for producers

There is an excellent article on the history of tv show credits here: [A brief history of TV shows' opening credit sequences](https://theweek.com/articles/632836/brief-history-tv-shows-opening-credit-sequences)

In it, it talks about how after a tradition of longer sequences, the need for them declined as audiences wanted to get straight to the action.

Following the example of *Lost*, and its 15 second intro, other shows began adopting a similar approach to shorter sequences:

> [Lost’s] minimalist approach demonstrated TV shows didn't need credits or a catchy theme songs to set a tone and get viewers; cast members could be introduced during the first scene, and people would still watch. Title cards also allowed shows to "dive right into the action," providing more screen time per episode. And of course, minimalist credits meant money saved.

A few years later, and it’s clear that audiences responded to the change:

> By 2006, **only about 10 percent of shows used a theme song or credit sequence to set up the story**. "Clearly, brevity is key," The Associated Press reported in 2006. "No drawn-out intro or hokey theme. Networks don't have time for that — and neither, prevailing TV thinking goes, do the country's couch potatoes."

My own view is that with binge watching more and more common, the need for an engaged, long-term, viewer of a show to sit through a long introduction is reduced. They already know the characters, the setting and the theme - they’d rather get to the story.

This is evident by Netflix’s introduction of a ‘Skip intro’ button.

Comment: Amazon Prime Video has a "Skip Intro" button, too, at least via TiVo.

Comment: These are great points!  As a counter-point (or separate point anyways), I know some shows (*The Simpsons* and likely others, primarily animated) kept their intro "dynamic", so if the show didn't have the full 22 mins of content, they could extend the into (e.g. via the "Couch Gag" for *The Simpsons*).  But the last point you made is probably the most applicable here and going forward, IMO.